# Print all 7 dates of a week based on month number (in a year) and week number (of exact month) in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a weekly template for personal planning in Google Sheets.

I have 3 variables in cells:

- year number (2023)
- month number (1- January, 2- February, etc)
- week number (1 - 4 week in that month)

I need to have formula based dates printed horisontaly, that will be based on those 3 variables.

Lets say:

- A1 - year
- B1 - month number
- C1 - week number (of month)

How would formula for dates look like?

**UPD 1:** I guess that i need to find week number inside a year firstly. And after that obtain dates of that week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it similar, but you should define how is week of the month defined. When you put 2, you expect to start from the second monday?, second sunday?, or from the 8th day?

This formula would do it from the 8th day:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,7,DATE(A1,B1,1+7*(C1-1)))
```

If you specify your logic, I can be more specific or you may be able to find it yourself!

### UPDATE

Try with this to count weeks from the first monday (or previous):

```
=SEQUENCE(1,7,DATE(A1,B1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,B1,1),2)+1+(C1-1)*7)
```

Comment: i have 3 variables (year num, month num, and week inside month num (always 1 to 4))
Week always start from monday.

Comment: if i put 2 in a week cell i expect dates to begin from monday of a second week, like if A1 - 2023, B1 - 2, C1 - 2 : dates would be staring from 06.02.2023, 07.02.2023 etc.. ALso, week can often start not from 01 digit, but from previous month like 30, 31..

Comment: I guess that i need firstly to count week number inside a year, based on month and order of monthly week, and after that to get the dates.

Comment: Thanks! That works as i expected!)